# using generated staticEXIOptions.c using exipg utility

Tags: c++, exi

I am using exipg utility from exip for generating EXI grammar definitions for
schema-enabled EXI processing. Since my schema is static I have used static option.

```
exipg −static −schema=EXIOptions−xsd.exi staticEXIOptions.c
```

Question is How I can use the generated staticEXIOptions.c? I could not find any example in example files which they provided with exip package.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I could add the generated file to my build system and use it.
We need to pass EXIPSchema object present in generated file to parse.setSchema() while parsing.